# Android app unexpectedly quitted when I closed the bluetooth serversocket or bluetooth socket

Tags: android, bluetooth

The android app quitted without any warning and error when bluetoothServersocket.close() called in the main thread while bluetoothServersocket.accept(); was blocked for incoming connections in another thread.

Here is pieces of my code.

> > public void run() {
> >
> > > > try {
> > > >
> > > > > > bluetoothServerSocket = BluetoothAdapter.
> > > > > >             getDefaultAdapter().listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(LISTEN_NAME, LISTEN_UUID);
> > > > > >
> > > > > > /* the thread blocked here for incoming connections */
> > > > > >
> > > > > > bluetoothSocket = bluetoothServerSocket.accept();
> > > > > >
> > > > > > ...
> > > >
> > > > } catch(Exception e) {} finally {
> > > >
> > > > > > try {bluetoothServerSocket.close();} catch(Exception ex) {}
> > > > > >
> > > > > > try {bluetoothSocket.close();} catch(Exception ex) {}
> > > >
> > > > }
> >
> > }

And in the activity.

> > public void onStop () {
> >
> > > > try{thread.bluetoothSocket.close();} catch(Exception ex) {}
> > > >
> > > > try{thread.bluetoothServerSocket.close();} catch(Exception ex) {}
> > > >
> > > > super.onStop();
> >
> > }

When I clicked the back button. The activity closed but after about one second the app quitted without any warning.

My android os version is 2.2. a HTC Desire device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should close a bluetooth connection like this:

> > try { synchronized (bluetoothServerSocket) {bluetoothServerSocket.close();}} catch(Exception ex) {}